# Bottom Panel shows the name of the active application and workspace indicator in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, taskbar

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I think there's a weird bug on the dock.

[image: m]

Is there any way to make that disappear? It's giving me Windows Vista vibes.